# How to pass a variable to jquery, then load result in div?

Tags: jquery

I need to be able to pass a variable from the link to jquery, then load the results in a div. What I'm doing is below, but it's not working for me. I feel like I'm close, but not quite there.

I've searched and found many similar questions, but none are quite what I'm looking for. What I have below is the result of those searches, and it's not working, so I'm doing something wrong.

Any help?

jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 

$.ajaxSetup ({
cache: false
});

$(function() {
    $('.dellink').click( function() {
        $.get( $(this).attr('href'), function() {
            // $('#eventlist').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#eventlist').load('/events/admin/eventlist.cfm');
     });
        return false; // don't follow the link!
    });
});

});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div>Item in a list of items I wish to delete...<a href="delevent.cfm?eventid=31" class="dellink"><img src="assets/images/delete.png" alt=""></a></div>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you have an error in the console?

Comment: Also you don't need to use both `$(document).ready(function() {` and `$(function() {` as these do the same thing (and using both can actually cause issues)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dellink').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.get(url, function(data) {
      $('#eventlist').load('/events/admin/eventlist.cfm');
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I can't get this to work at all. Even after I added the missing );

Comment: Any errors in the console? I wasn't able to test that code but it should be very close. Normally I wouldn't use the href for deleting records. I would add an attribute like data-id='2' to each record and then just pass that id around. How far did you get? Is the record deleted?

Comment: This did in fact work. It had other issues due to some other things I am doing on the page, but as is provided, works very well for it's intended purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If i did understand right, before you make the get request you need to change #eventid# for some real id to pass to server side code.

```
var url = $(this).attr('href').replace('#eventid#',someRealId);
$.get( url, function() {
    // $('#eventlist').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#eventlist').load('/events/admin/eventlist.cfm');
});
```

Another thing: Do you expects to receive some data from the first request? If so, you need to explicitly put a parameter on the success function. The code below is a example from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

I suggest make only one request for deletion and receive as result a updated list of events, because, as you can see in the code below, `.load()` is simple a shortcut from `.get()` example above.

```
$('.result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your solution does the delete function in the action file, but also refreshes the page to show the item has been removed from the list. I'm trying to avoid that by using load(). I don't want the page to reload, just the contents of #eventlist.

Comment: I think the page is not reloaded because of load() or get(), but because of the link's behavior. Vlad gave a solution for that using e.preventDefault. Try to mixing the answers, maybe works.